# Total number of records in Firebase (when am I done counting?)

Tags: firebase

Counting records in a table is obviously a manual effort until you guys get some of that spiffy new functionality already in the works ;)

However, I'm stuck on even using a manual run with .on('value', ...) to fetch a count:

```
var table = new Firebase('http://beta.firebase.com/user/tablename');
var count = 0;
table.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   count++;
   // how do I know if this is the last child? i.e. the count is complete?
});

// when is it okay to use count?
```

I foresee the same issues with any sort of pagination and I feel like I'm being a bit blockheaded about this. What am I missing?

Is this fundamentally the wrong pattern for, say, getting the number of messages a user has in his/her queue?

Comment: Try this
Use javascript object count, it work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With "child_added" there is no way to know when you've received the "last" item. If you're looking to count all of the children that existed at a particular point in time, I'd suggest using the "value" event as follows:

```
var table = new Firebase('http://beta.firebase.com/user/tablename');

table.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   var count = 0;
   snapshot.forEach(function() {
       count++;
   });
   //count is now safe to use.
});
```

Comment: Yeah, being blockheaded. I had discounted using `forEach` because it requires calling `value` on the parent, which can be a large overhead on big tables. Somewhere, I slipped it entirely. :)

Answer (score 7):

The child_added event has no notion of "done", since children can continue to be added over time.  If you want to get a count of the children *right now*, you can use 'value' to get the current snapshot from that location and then count the children.  For example:

```
table.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var count = 0;
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    count++;
  });
  // do something with count.
});
```

Alternatively, if you want the count to continually update, you can use .on() instead of .once() above.  But this isn't ideal performance-wise, since you'll be counting all of the children every time.  Fortunately, you can use a combination of 'child_added' and 'value' to efficiently keep a count:

```
var count = 0;
table.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  count++;
  // how do I know if this is the last child? i.e. the count is complete?
});

table.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  // do something with count.
});
```

This works since 'value' will fire once after the "initial" data is complete and then again whenever the data changes, so you'll get a continually updating correct count.  Though you'll need to handle child_removed as well if you expect children to be removed.

Comment: Right, for some reason I forgot about getting the snapshot and using forEach after our discussion about the overhead involved in calling `value` on the parent table. What my brain heard: "delete value/forEach from memory" :(  See? I knew it was obvious.

Comment: Haha.  Well, glad it makes sense now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Until FB implements count as a returned function, I guess the best way to not have client side loop through any returned records is to fetch it the REST way.

ref: [What’s the best RESTful method to return total number of items in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/whats-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object)