# REST API for retrieving object set cardinality

Tags: api, rest

Good practices for designing REST APIs say that one should use:

- `GET` requests for the selection of an object (or a collection of objects)
- `POST` requests for the creation of a new object

A pair of examples taken from [here](http://codeplanet.io/principles-good-restful-api-design/):

- `GET`: `https://example.org/api/v1/zoos` selects all the zoos
- `POST`: `https://example.org/api/v1/zoos` creates a new zoo

Now, all these methods are designed to either retrieve an instance (or a set of instances) or modify some instance status.

What about retrieving some statistics on those resources that are stored on the server (e.g., number of zoos stored on the server)?
I would not expect something that requires me to download the entire collection and then count the number of documents. Still, I am not sure what should be the right syntax. Is the following:

`https://example.org/api/v1/zoos/number`

a proper way of doing it? If not, which is the best practice?

Comment: `https://example.org/api/v1/zoos/number` or `/count` seems fine, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/whats-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, REST APIs are usually segregated by {Resource}/{Action}/{Parameter}.

I recommend using:

```
/zoos/count
```

`count` tells me what you want to do with the `zoos` resource.

Comment: I agree with this approach

Comment: Be careful with the phrasing here. The URI is supposed to be a 'thing', not an action. AS such, perhaps `/Zoos/stats/count` would be better. `stats` would be like a meta resource of the `Zoos` resource and we are accessing the `count` resource in particular. There might also be something like `/Zoos/stats/last_update` or `/Zoos/stats/admin` etc.