# Strongloop API GET request does not return item/record count

Tags: strongloop

I am new to strongloop api, but I have some experience in using other apis.
While using strongloop api for building pagination feature, I came to know that **strongloop api does not return total records in result, neither in response body nor in headers**

I was looking for functionality similar to this.
[What’s the best RESTful method to return total number of items in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/whats-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object)

My question is
**Is there any other way of achieving same using strongloop api?**

I have checked the strongloop api and stackoverflow questions, but didnt get
satisfactory results.

I think this is very basic functionality, it must have been implemented there. Any suggestions would help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using remote hooks? http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not satisfy the question. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: The result of any select query is an array. You can get the length of the array object.

Answer (score 4):

To find the total count of records, 
you can use REST API or NodeJS call. Other options are also available in SDKs such as Angular SDK for strong with minor variations in the format of the query

REST API:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3001/api/brands/count
```

Node

```
    var Brand = app.models.brand;
    Brand.count(function (err, count) {
        console.log(count);
        }
    });
```

To do pagination, use:{"skip":40,"limit":10} eg:

```
    var Brand = app.models.Brand;
    Brand.find({
        skip: 30,
        limit: 20
    }, function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    })
```

This will give you a paginated data. You can also use where condition, sorting etc... in combination with the above codes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is just the count and you do not mind making a second request just to get the count then Strongloop does have a support for that: `api/<YOUR-MODLE-NAME>/count`

But I assume what you want is to make only one request and get both the count and the data, if that is the case then you can do this with a remote hook to add this extra bit of information either in the header, or in the result itself.

To add the total count in the header, have a look at this thread in GitHub, someone has posted code sample to add in X-Total-Count in the returned header:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1411

You can also use an afterRemote hook in your model and change the result returned to add in the count somewhere. Here is an example:

```
module.exports = function (Model) {
    Model.afterRemote('find', function (ctx, model, next) {
        Model.count().then(function (totalCount) {
            ctx.result = {
                total: totalCount,
                items: model
            };
            next();
        });
    });
};
```

Assuming you are using Strongloop API v3, have a look at the remote hook session of their documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html

Hope this helps.