# REST Best Practise : Return Count with List API

Tags: rest

We have a REST Service endpoint

OUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users

This endpoint returns list of active users in our application. Now we need to show total user count as well. For this we thought about two approaches

1. Add another field in response for count in same listing service end point

> { count : 15, users :[{...},{...}] }

2. Develop a separate service to return count only

> OUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users : for user listing
>
> OUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/userscount : for user count

I personally prefer option 1 but option 2 seems logical too as according to REST best practises, one REST End Point should serve one specific purpose only. Please suggest according to REST best practises which option is better and why?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What’s the best RESTful method to return total number of items in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/what-s-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object)

Comment: @Leponzo hanks for your response but the link is doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are two approach to do that:

- **In the payload**. This corresponds to your first option. It implies a different structure for the returned data than the flat one but it's really acceptable
- **In the headers**. You can add an header like `X-total-count` for this. There is also the `Link` header that is linked if you want to implement pagination. See the Github API for a sample: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination.

A separate service returning the number of elements isn't really RESTful since you use a specific verb in the resource path...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case I'd suggest option 1. It is perfectly acceptable from a REST perspective, and is a widely used approach. On a more general level, if your service doesn't support pagination, you shoud give the caller the chance to know how many results will be returned before they actually send the request. The purpose is to let the caller know beforehand whether the response is going to "flood" him with too many results. In this case option 2 is acceptable, even though it adds the (avoidable) overhead of adding a separate call. As a final note, I'd suggest to add another path fragment called 'size', so that the url becomes e.g.

```
DOMAIN/api/v2/users/size
```

which has no verbs.