# Designing REST api for returning count of multiple objects

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a question on how should I design my rest api(s) given that I need to return count of different objects in my application. There are multiple approaches that could be thought off

1. Defining a single api that generally accepts the object identifier in the request body (json) and returns back the count for each of the object identifiers in the response. The drawback is the api is too generic and possibly not restful since there is no resource. The url would look like GET /counts
2. Define individual api's for each of the resources for which count is needed. Assuming I need to return counts for the fields defined in the software, tables, processes, tasks, jobs etc I would define individual api's for each of these resources. It would look like GET /field/count or GET /table/count. A side effect of this would be there would be many web api's for each of the resources we need the count for. Is that bad?

Kindly share your thoughts on the above approaches and any new ways in which I could design such an API that adheres to the REST standards.

Thanks

Comment: Why to use different API for counts ? What is driving for count data ? If it is for UI - only one at a time ? or all information should be at once ?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't exactly a "REST standard" and the idea of "restful URLs" is pretty much a subjective matter. The core REST WS principles are mostly concerned with other things, among which is proper use of HTTP and providing information that could theoretically allow automatic processes to "understand" the resources and API (this is rarely implemented in common "restful" interfaces). That being said, I'd go for the 2nd variant simply because it makes more natural sense (i.e. resources are differentiated) - but then again if your resource is a "count" then the first also works.

Comment: Yeah returning all information at once would be better. What should the url look like?
What do you mean by "count as a resource"?

Any other approaches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the best RESTful method to return total number of items in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/what-s-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the client that is consuming the APIs.

**Case 1**. If its a WebApp which needs count of many tables on a single page then both will lead to bad design where you will have to make hundreds of calls just for counts data. You can club counts in a single API and send that as a response.

**Case 2**. If the client are individually using the count then i would recommend the 2nd approach where the resource is clearly defined. For the 2nd approach you are making the client intelligent which is not recommended.

As mentioned in the comments REST is a totally subjective topic so there can be multiple view points to every design.