# REST API: Should we have separate API for result and result count?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, api-design

I am confused whether we should create separate API for fetching result and result-count OR we should fetch count based on query string in the result API only.

```
/api/results/ : Fetches all records
/api/results/?city=1: Fetches all records with city=1
/api/results/?iscount=1: Fetches the count of records i.e. list of cityId and count of record for respective cityId
/api/results/?city=1&iscount=1: Fetch the count of record for cityId=1
```

OR

```
/api/resultcount/: Fetches the count of records i.e. list of cityId and count of record for respective cityId
/api/resultcount/?city=1: Fetch the count of record for cityId=1
```

To me query string is used for filtering of resource so, I am in favor of creating separate API for fetching the counts. Opinion?

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to create another point for fetching the count. Instead, we can send the count details in the response header.

It will be something like below,

`/api/results/(GET method)` - This will return the results.

`/api/results/(HEAD method)` - This will just return the results count in the response header.

Please take a look at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715981/what-s-the-best-restful-method-to-return-total-number-of-items-in-an-object?)

Comment: The problem with the `HEAD /api/results` is that the server-side query will have to actually fetch the results, when all you want is a count (less intensive query).